# Fill up a dictionary in parallel with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocess

Yesterday i asked a question: [Reading data in parallel with multiprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378310/reading-data-in-parallel-with-multiprocess)

I got very good answers, and i implemented the solution mentioned in the answer i marked as correct.

```
def read_energies(motif):
    os.chdir("blabla/working_directory")
    complx_ener = pd.DataFrame()
    # complex function to fill that dataframe 
    lig_ener = pd.DataFrame()
    # complex function to fill that dataframe 
    return motif, complx_ener, lig_ener

COMPLEX_ENERGIS = {}
LIGAND_ENERGIES = {}
p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=CPU)
for x in p.imap_unordered(read_energies, peptide_kd.keys()):
    COMPLEX_ENERGIS[x[0]] = x[1]
    LIGAND_ENERGIES[x[0]] = x[2]
```

However, this solution takes the same amount of time as if i would just iterate over `peptide_kd.keys()` and fill up the `DataFrames` one by one. Why is that so? Is there a way to fill up the desired dicts in parallel and actually get a speed increase? i am running it on a 48 core HPC.

Comment: It may be that the overhead of using multiprocessing is greater than that of doing the complex function processing. Perhaps having `read_energies()` process a variable number dataframes each time would allow you to tune things to the point were there it became advantageous.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are incurring a good amount of overhead in (1) starting up each process, and (2) having to copy the `pandas.DataFrame` (and etc) across several processes.  If you just need to have a `dict` filled in parallel, I'd suggest using a shared memory `dict`.  If no key will be overwritten, then it's easy and you don't have to worry about locks.

(Note I'm using `multiprocess` below, which is a fork of `multiprocessing` -- but only so I can demonstrate from the interpreter, otherwise, you'd have to do the below from `__main__`).

```
>>> from multiprocess import Process, Manager
>>> 
>>> def f(d, x):
...   d[x] = x**2
... 
>>> manager = Manager()
>>> d = manager.dict()
>>> job = [Process(target=f, args=(d, i)) for i in range(5)]
>>> _ = [p.start() for p in job]
>>> _ = [p.join() for p in job]
>>> print d
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16}
```

This solution doesn't make copies of the `dict` to share across processes, so that part of the overhead is reduced. For large objects like a `pandas.DataFrame`, it can be significant compared to the cost of a simple operation like `x**2`.  Similarly, spawning a `Process` can take time, and you maybe be able to do the above even faster (for lightweight objects) by using threads (i.e. from `multiprocess.dummy` instead of `multiprocess` for either your originally posted solution or mine above).

If you *do* need to share `DataFrames` (as your code suggests instead of as the question asks), you might be able to do it by creating a shared memory `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am going to try this now, but first i would like to ask something. I don't understand the difference between the mentioned `shared` dataframes (variables i guess). Why does my code imply that i use a shared DataFrame? The job i want to do in parallel is as you described, fill up a dictionary, and use it afterwards in different ways (read the data inside it), but don't change anything inside it.

Comment: The reason I said you might look into shared memory arrays is that you are returning two `DataFrame` instances from each `Process`.  However, it's hard to point you to whether you need to do that or not, as you only presented meta-code.

Comment: Ohh I see. I need both of the `DataFrames`. is it problematic to return two of them? Would it be easier to do this in two separate steps?

Comment: No it't not problematic to return both, it's just expensive.  you could however, make two shared memory array that are not returned… and just fill up the `DataFrame.values` accordingly.

Comment: I just want to thank you again for this great answer, it took me some time to fully understand it ( I am a bio engineer, i am just learning to code efficiently now) but i learned a lot from this. Sad i can't give you more upvotes :)

Comment: No worries.  I'm glad it helped.

Comment: where are you setting the number of processes ?

Comment: @Curious: Each invocation of `Process` creates a new process, so I'm setting the number of processes with `range(5)`.